# Query not running correctly - SQlite Android Studio

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I have this function that should insert data into the SQlite DB and return false if the data doesn't get inserted however the function returns true but when I go to check the .db file there's no data in the table.

```
public boolean insertData(String name, String emailAddress, String postalAddress, String password, int phoneNumber, String bloodType) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //set data to columns
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, emailAddress);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, postalAddress);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, password);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, phoneNumber);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, bloodType);

    //inserts data into db
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //checks to see if data has been inserted correctly
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;


}
```

the image below shows that the table and database have been created correctly.

[image: database info]

Comment: *when I go to check the .db file there's no data in the table*. Extract from the device not only the database file but 2 more files with names ending with -wal and -shm. Place all 3 files inside a folder and then open the database.

Comment: @forpas I can't find those files in the directory

Comment: Then try by uninstalling the app from the device and rerun or even better try with a clean device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `#beginTransaction()`, `#setTransactionSuccessful()` and `#endTransaction()` like described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction()).

> The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful).

```
public boolean insertData(String name, String emailAddress, String postalAddress, String password, int phoneNumber, String bloodType) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, emailAddress);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, postalAddress);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, password);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, phoneNumber);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, bloodType);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        return result != -1;
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, there's still nothing in the table